# AllJoyn Audio service compilation problems

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, alljoyn

I want to run an audio streaming server based on [AllJoyn](https://www.alljoyn.org) and the AllJoyn audio service doesn't seem to be buildable from the *alljoyn/multimedia/audio* folder (running scons in this folder always ends up in compilation errors). I'm building AllJoyn version 14.06.

Anybody successfully built the AllJoyn audio service on a Raspberry Pi (Raspbian)?

Thx a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to compile the audio service you need to do it from the folder *alljoyn/core/alljoyn/services/audio*
This is an example compilation command (targetting a Raspberry Pi) that also builds the audio samples:

```
scons OS=linux CPU=arm WS=fix BR=on SERVICES=about,audio BUILD_SERVICES_SAMPLES=on VARIANT=release BINDINGS=core,cpp OE_BASE=/usr
```

You'll have to install the packages *libasound2* and *libasound2-dev* before compiling though. You can test if it works by running the file *SinkService* from the samples and streaming music to it from the Android app doubleTwist. If the music plays too fast make sure you modify the *SConscript* in *alljoyn/multimedia/audio* to include the asound library in the environment:

```
if audio_env['OS'] == 'linux':
        audio_env.AppendUnique(LIBS = [ 'asound' ])
```

If trying to build the audio service but for Android you should check [this page](https://ask.allseenalliance.org/question/154/unable-to-build-alljoyn-audio-service-framework-for-android/). If you can't connect to the *SinkService* from doubleTwist after building see [this page](https://github.com/doubletwist/magicplay-arm/issues/1). If you can connect but *SinkService* hangs see [this page](https://ask.allseenalliance.org/question/1197/fast-audio-fixed-but-now-sinkservice-hangs-upon-connection/).

If your intention is to build all AllJoyn services and bindings switch to *alljoyn/core/alljoyn* folder and try something like this:

```
scons OS=linux CPU=arm WS=fix BR=on SERVICES=about,audio,config,controlpanel,notification,onboarding BUILD_SERVICES_SAMPLES=on VARIANT=release BINDINGS=core,cpp,c,java,js,objc,unity OE_BASE=/usr
```

HTH